# Failed login and redirect from Okta login page

Tags: spring, redirect, okta

I am using Spring Security to authenticate with SAML and Okta, generally it works, I am able to authenticate a user and access secured URLs within my application. So far so good.

Now I have a requirement for a special type of 'internal' users to use different authentication mechanism (those users will not be in AD nor Okta) - so if authentication fails using Okta I want to display different login page. Problem is that I am unable to redirect from Okta login page to my custom page after unsuccessful login, seems like Okta will not redirect even after many unsuccessful attempts.

Is there a way to implement such requirement?

Answer (score 0):

You can't redirect Okta on a failed authentication. You will need to determine what type of authentication to use prior to validating the username and password. Okta supports application based custom login page and so when the user tries to access the application, Okta redirects to your login page. From there your login page will determine where to authenticate the user.

[**Okta configuration for custom login page**](https://support.okta.com/help/articles/Knowledge_Article/Redirecting-Users-to-a-Custom-Login-Page)

You can use [Okta's Authentication APIs](http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/authn.html) and [SDKs](http://developer.okta.com/docs/sdk/core/api.html) to authenticate against AD and custom code.

Comment: Are you saying there is no way to redirect the user back to the application even when Sign in fails to display a custom error page within the application rather than staying at the Okta login form seeing the Okta "Sign in failed!" message?